# CATextLayer in SCNBox shows in portrait mode

Tags: ios, calayer, arkit, catextlayer

I am trying to write text onto a SCNBox node. I see the text in the box but the text orientation is portrait. How do I make this landscape?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNqNk.png)

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer new]; 
[layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; 
[layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];

CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer new];
[textLayer setFrame:[layer bounds]];
[textLayer setFontSize:24];
[textLayer setString:@"TEST"];
[textLayer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentLeft];
[textLayer setForegroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[textLayer display];
[layer addSublayer:textLayer];

SCNBox *box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:2 length:0.005 chamferRadius:0.0];
[[[box firstMaterial] diffuse] setContents:layer];
// [[[box firstMaterial] diffuse] setContents:[UIColor redColor]]; 
[[box firstMaterial] setLightingModelName:SCNLightingModelConstant]; 
[[box firstMaterial] setDoubleSided:YES]; 
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate your textLayer like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.angle);  // angle in radians
label.transform = transform;
```